# Vertically align text in anchor tag styled like a button

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox, anchor

I'm trying to style some anchor tags to look exactly like my buttons. Both of them have given a common class:

```css
.xButton {
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 1.2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
```

Despite this, the vertical alignment of the text inside the anchor tag is towards the top.
[In pic attached, the bottom one is the anchor tag, first one is button. This is the case even without icons btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf2g7.png)

Manually adding `vertical-align: bottom` or `vertical-align: center` doesn't seem to work. Interestingly, when I do `all: unset` on the common class, the button's text similarly vertically-aligns to the top.

**Edit:** To clarify, even without icons the text looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5myBI.png). This is even if `text-align: center` rule is added.

### Update!

[For some reason, changing the font-family of the common class (.xButton) to Arial from the custom font Hind fixed the issue...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX4V2.png)
I'm not sure why there is an issue when using the custom font and where I can report it to..

---

**The whole code, for reference**:
The component:

```html
---
import type { HTMLAttributes } from "astro/types";

type Props = HTMLAttributes<"a"> & HTMLAttributes<"button">;
const { class: className, type = "button", ...attrs } = Astro.props as Props;
const isAnchor = "href" in Astro.props;
---

{
  !isAnchor ? (
    <button class:list={['xButton' , className]} type={type} {...attrs}>
      <slot />
    </button>
  ) : (
    <a class:list={['xButton' , className]} {...attrs}>
      <slot />
    </a>
  )
}

<style>

  .xButton {
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .xButton > svg {
    height: 1.2em;
    width: auto;
  }

  .xButton.primary {
    color: var(--neutral-swatch-900);
    background-color: var(--primary-swatch-100);
  }

  .xButton.secondary {
    background-color: var(--primary-swatch-800);
    color: var(--primary-swatch-100);
  }

  :global(.dark) .xButton.primary {
    color: var(--neutral-swatch-100);
    background: var(--neutral-swatch-900);
  }

  :global(.dark) .xButton.secondary {
    background-color: var(--primary-swatch-100);
    color: var(--neutral-swatch-800);  
  }

  .xButton:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.3);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

</style>
```

Where it's being called:

```html
      <nav>
        <XButton class="primary">
          Launch Lab&nbsp; <FlaskIcon/>
        </XButton>

        <XButton href="https://github.com/xylarshayu" rel="noopener" target="_blank" class="secondary">
          Go to Github&nbsp; <GithubLogo/>
        </XButton>
      </nav>
```

(The Icons work as just SVGs, I've used https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons for this.)

Comment: Could you send through the working bit of code your using? With the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Changing display in your css from `display: inline-flex;` to `display: block;` will make your button on top each other. Then, adding margin make them separate apart. I will add snippet for your reference.

```css
.xButton {
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    display: block;
    margin: 25px;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 1.2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.xButton:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="xButton">Launch Lab</button>
<button class="xButton">Go to Github</button>
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: It needs to be inline :( also using inline-block didn't seem to vertically align the text in the middle either...

Comment: Can you provide a code playground to check your code easier?